# Should I use IOCPs or overlapped WSASend/Receive?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, winsock, iocp

I am investigating the options for asynchronous socket I/O on Windows. There is obviously more than one option: I can use WSASend... with an overlapped structure providing either a completion callback or an event, or I could use IOCPs and the (new) thread pool. From I usually read, the latter option is the recommended one.

However, it is not clear to me, why I should use IOCPs if the completion routine suffices for my goal: tell the socket to send this block of data and inform me if it is done.

I understand that the IOCP stuff in combination with `CreateThreadpoolIo` etc. uses the OS thread pool. However, the "normal" overlapped I/O must also use separate threads? So what is the difference/disadvantage? Is my callback called by an I/O thread and blocks other stuff?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either but, for servers, IOCP with the 'completion queue' will have better performance, in general, because it can use multiple client<>server threads, either with CreateThreadpoolIo or some user-space thread pool.  Obviously, in this case, dedicated handler threads are usual.

Overlapped completion-routine I/O is more useful for clients, IMHO. The completion-routine is fired by an Asynchronous Procedure Call that is queued to the thread that initiated the I/O request, (WSASend, WSARecv). This implies that that thread must be in a position to process the APC and typically this means a while(true) loop around some 'blahEx()' call.  This can be useful because it's fairly easy to wait on a blocking queue, or other inter-thread signal, that allows the thread to be supplied with data to send and the completion routine is always handled by that thread.  This I/O mechanism leaves the 'hEvent' OVL parameter free to use - ideal for passing a comms buffer object pointer into the completion routine.

Overlapped I/O using an actual synchro event/Semaphore/whatever for the overlapped hEvent parameter should be avoided.

Comment: Why should the synchrnonization event approach be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Windows IOCP documentation recommends no more than one thread per available core per completion port. Hyperthreading doubles the number of cores. Since use of IOCPs results in a for all practical purposes event-driven application the use of thread pools adds unnecessary processing to the scheduler.

If you think about it you'll understand why: an event should be serviced in its entirety (or placed in some queue after initial processing) as quickly as possible. Suppose five events are queued to an IOCP on a 4-core computer. If there are eight threads associated with the IOCP you run the risk of the scheduler interrupting one event to begin servicing another by using another thread which is inefficient. It can be dangerous too if the interrupted thread was inside a critical section. With four threads you can process four events simultaneously and as soon as one event has been completed you can start on the last remaining event in the IOCP queue.

Of course, you may have thread pools for non-IOCP related processing.

***EDIT***__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_

The socket (file handles work fine too) is associated with an IOCP. The completion routine waits on the IOCP. As soon as a requested read from or write to the socket completes the OS - via the IOCP - releases the completion routine waiting on the IOCP and returns with the additional information you provided when you called the read or write (I usually pass a pointer to a control block). So the completion routine immediately "knows" where the to find information pertinent to the completion.

If you passed information referring to a control block (similar) then that control block (probably) needs to keep track of what operation has completed so it knows what to do next. The IOCP itself neither knows nor cares.

If you're writing a server attached to the internet, the server would issue a read to wait for client input. That input may arrive a milli-second or a week later and when it does the IOCP will release the completion routine which analyzes the input. Typically it responds with a write containing the data requested in the input and then waits on the IOCP. When the write completed the IOCP again releases the completion routine which sees that the write has completed, (typically) issues a new read and a new cycle starts.

So an IOCP-based application typically consumes very little (or no) CPU until the moment a completion occurs at which time the completion routine goes full tilt until it has finished processing, sends a new I/O request and again waits on the completion port. Apart from the IOCP timeout (which can be used to signal house-keeping or such) all I/O-related stuff occurs in the OS.

To further complicate (or simplify) things it is not necessary that sockets be serviced using the WSA routines, the Win32 functions ReadFile and WriteFile work just fine.

Comment: That all assumes that the work your threads does never blocks (which would be ideal but isn't always possible). Having extra threads waiting on the IOCP can help if the threads CAN block; profile and see. Having your own thread pool can help if you want to ensure that your I/O is processed ahead of other potential users of a shared pool, etc. Ideally each 'connection' (completion key) object has its own internal queue so that if you get multiple completions (read and write?) for the same 'connection' you don't use up two of your IOCP threads and have them fighting over the same 'connection'...

Comment: @Olof: So you would still recommend IOCPs instead of overlapped I/O, but I should dedicate a single thread to a completion port. Did I get this right? And doesn't that limit the number of handles I should associate with the port (using the `ExistingCompletionPort` parameter)?

Comment: IOCPs are overlapped I/O but they are much more efficient than waiting on multiple objects (which essentially is a form of polling). You should have no more threads waiting on an IOCP than you have cores (a core with hyperthreading counts as two) in the system. So if you have four cores you should not have more than four threads waiting on an IOCP. Of course, if you have two IOCPs then you should not have more than four threads each (and maybe adjust thread priorities as I have).